# A VF page calls an instance method via an action method - but there are 2 instance methods. How does this work?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am playing around with levergaing Google Visualizations API with Salesforce data and displaying that nicely on a Visualforce page*.

In this [class](https://github.com/meilingkuan/apex-google-visualization/blob/master/GoogleVisualizations/src/classes/SalesController.cls), as per lines 34 - 36, it's an instance method of type that takes no parms and returns null.

```
public String getSalesActivity(){
        return getSalesActivity(null);
    }
```

In line 38, we see the same instance method that takes a list of Ids, and then the GoogleViz class being instantiated with some logic etc:

```
public String getSalesActivity(List<Id> ids){
```

The component that I'm using in a Visualforce page makes the call to the method:

```
<c:Timeline jsondata="{!SalesActivity}"
```

and everything is acting as expected.

1) But I am confused why there are two instance methods of the same name, one that takes no parameters and another that takes a List of Ids as a parameter...how come the action method in the Visualforce component knows which method to call?

2) And why does it no longer return data if I comment out the first instance method?

It seems like this is similar in some sense to apex properties.

Thanks,

*
https://github.com/meilingkuan/apex-google-visualization
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Google_Visualizations
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery?csw=1

Comment: It always calls the signature with no parameters.

Comment: You'll need to adapt the method `getSalesActivity()` to fetch a list of IDs and then do `return getSalesActivity(that list of ids)`